# Array formula to subtract two named ranges, and count the values that are <15 and greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two named ranges r_hire_date, and r_birth year.

I am trying to get rid of creating an intermediary step which involves creating a separate column, "Hire Year - Birth year". The column " Hire Year - Birth Year" is the year( first reference in r_hire_date) - first reference in r_birth_year. I then assign the new column as r_diff_hr_age_brth_age, and perform the below countifs.

```
=COUNTIFS(r_diff_hr_age_brth_age,"<"&15,r_diff_hr_age_brth_age,">"&0)
```

How can I go about doing this by simply leveraging array formulas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SUMPRODUCT to compare subtracting one array from the other and checking against your conditions e.g.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(r_hire_date-r_birth_year>0),--(r_hire_date-r_birth_year<15))
```